# restoring database mysqldump (good practice?)

Tags: magento2, database

I always worked on my projects with GIT and major frameworks can do the migrations through the code, so the problem of database dependency is solved.

But here in Magento2 I don't know if I'm going on the good way.

I configured all the stuff that only is saved on database like stores configuration, locate, etc. So I did a mysqldump.

Then for testing, I created a production environment and I uploaded the code, installed magento and restored this mysqldump.

I figured out I had to change the base_url: on the table `core_config_data` the line 2 `web/unsecure/base_url`.

And that's all I changed for now, but I think I'm missing something. For example when I enter to admin panel, it disconnects me from another page like is the same user, but they are on different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides the `web/unsecure/base_url` you also need to change the `web/secure/base_url`.

Another step is to check your **local.xml** file to make sure you have the right access information to the database.

I believe that this link can also be helpful for you:
http://www.itworld.com/article/2833094/it-management/how-to-copy-a-magento-installation-to-a-new-domain.html